# Programmatically set button text

Tags: button, text, clarion

How do you programmatically set the button text in Clarion?  Obviously I can use the designer interface to set the default text on a control, but I want to be able to change the display text in the code.  Is there a way to do that?

I've tried things like the following, but nothing has worked or even compiled:

```
?Button1:Text = 'Test'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can programmatically set the text of a button in Clarion using `PROP:text`:

```
?Button1{PROP:Text} = 'Test'
```

I figured this out based on some research from another question I had [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24963687/1387518).