# Why not changing text on button when spinner option item Changed in android studio?

Tags: android, button, text, spinner

I'm trying to change the text of button accordingly when I click the options in spinnerin android studio.But in my app only text of TextView is changed, but the text of button is not changing.
What can I do? my Mainactivity class is Here [image: MainActivity 1st part]
 and [image: MainActivity 2nd part] 
Edit: My activity_main layout: [image: activity_main part 1] and [image: <code>activity_main part 2</code>]

Comment: Please provide your code in text format, not in an image.

Comment: sorry, I am a newbie.I can not find the option to attach text.Can you help? @lukegv

Comment: @suptagni take a look at the markdown editing docs for how to accomplish including code text: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. In brief, copy your code into the text editor and indent all of it. You can also wrap it in three backticks (`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically set button text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24939877/programmatically-set-button-text)

Answer (score 0):

You are only getting/setting the value of the text view, not the button view. You need to do something like:

```
button.setText("Your text");
```

In your `onItemSelected` section.

Comment: Then what these two lines are doing?   @BlackHatSamurai                                           remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.activity_main);                    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.button_id, "Click here option 2");

Comment: Not sure. It looks like they are creating new remote views. But they aren't the right thing to change the button text. You already have a reference to the button, you get it right beneath the text view. Just add `button.setText("whatever");` to your code.

Comment: but,there is showing an error on the  setText of button.It showing that setText can not be solved@BlackHatSamurai

Answer (score 0):

Alhamdulillah! At last I was able to solve the problem. I have updated the code as below : [image: Solved part]

Comment: yeah, you told me to add button.setText("whatever");  but only adding this didn't work. I had to add both lines consequently in both parts:                                Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_id);   button.setText("Click here ");       @BlackHatSamurai

Comment: Yes, you may have had to adjust your scope. You could have expanded the scope and made the button a class variable, or whatever. Glad I could help you out.